# Nested "using" crashes .net runtime when used with CryptoStream

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, .net-runtime

We have this simple code that was converted from vb.net where it wasn't constructed using `using/end using`. During conversion we utilized `using` in c#.

```
using (var memStream = new MemoryStream() { Position = 0L })
using (ICryptoTransform cryptoTransfrom = (new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider()).CreateDecryptor(_key, _iv))
{
    using (var cryptStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, cryptoTransfrom, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
        // <-- here used to be try
        string convertedValue = ConvertHexToDec(value);
        byte[] decryptBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(convertedValue); //<-- Error line
        // <-- here used to be catch/throw
        cryptStream.Write(decryptBytes, 0, decryptBytes.Length);
        cryptStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        cryptStream.Close();
    }
    decodedVal = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memStream.ToArray());
}
```

But there was `try/catch` (see comments) surrounding `Convert.FromBase64String(convertedValue)`. What we didn't realize, is that `value` sometimes came as plain, un-base64-encoded value. So, when un-encoded value hit "Error line" - `try/catch` did the business of re-throw. But, when you look at the code above, when such value causes exception at that line - .NET Runtime crashes. Here is event log

> .NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.5485 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (000007FEE581600A) (80131506)

And exception, of cource, just normal

> Invalid character in a Base-64 string.

I fixed it buy removing inner `using`

```
using (var memStream = new MemoryStream() { Position = 0L })
using (ICryptoTransform cryptoTransfrom = (new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider()).CreateDecryptor(_key, _iv))
{
    var cryptStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, cryptoTransfrom, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    string convertedValue = ConvertHexToDec(value);
    byte[] decryptBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(convertedValue); //<-- Error line      
    cryptStream.Write(decryptBytes, 0, decryptBytes.Length);
    cryptStream.FlushFinalBlock();
    cryptStream.Close();
    decodedVal = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memStream.ToArray());
}
```

Now, error, of course still, occurs but it doesn't crash .NET Runtime, therefore acts normal. Also, placing `try/catch-rethrow` where it was before would prevent such crash as well.

I suspect, it has something to do with nested `using`. Inner `using` is not really needed because `CryptoStream` simply wraps memory stream and transformation. And if error occurs inside curly brackets, it will be propagated to `try/catch` of transformation first and then memory stream.

But can someone explain such behavior considering that this only happens when assembly runs built for x64 and runs in x64 ASP.NET pool? When application compiled for x86 and runs in 32-bit pool, it doesn't happen.

Comment: Where does it crash?

Comment: Try to move `decodedVal = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memStream.ToArray());`  write after `cryptStream.FlushFinalBlock();`.

Comment: What do you mean "acts normal"?  `using` doesn't handle any thrown exceptions - it just ensures that the disposable component is disposed of whether there's an exception or not.

Comment: @DStanley And this what I mean precisely - just rethrows exception as usual. But with inner `using` it was crashing runtime environemnt

Comment: This does sound like it's a bug in the framework rather than in your code.

Comment: @T.S. so something upstream is handling the exception?

Comment: @T.S.: It sounds like Jon is agreeing with you, so I'm not sure why you're saying NO.

Comment: @DStanley Although there was handling way outside of this code, with inner `using` Runtime was crashing. There was no reach to `Catch` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is undoubtedly a bug in the runtime. Since you are using an extremely old version of the runtime, my advice is to upgrade.

> But can someone explain such behavior considering that this only happens when assembly runs built for x64 and runs in x64 ASP.NET pool? When application compiled for x86 and runs in 32-bit pool, it doesn't happen.

The x64 and x86 jitters were completely different codebases in that version. A bug severe enough to crash the runtime involving weird codegen bugs in nested try-finally blocks will almost certainly be unique to a particular jitter.

Comment: here is even more. My co-worker couldn't reproduce the issue. His NDP in registry is older than my HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727\version=2.0.50727.5420 (my) and his is something like 47xx or 49xx - and he is OK. We're working 24/7x1.5year on upgrade - removing 3rd party components that don't support 4+. 200 projects - not easy, while also developing new stuff in newer frameworks.